# Make concrete class instance from correlated generic payload in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

My goal is to take a generic payload object and create a concrete typed class instance from it based on the payload's `kind`.

It sounds like this should be possible with [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) but I'm failing to grasp it.

I have 20+ kinds to handle so I'd like to try to make this map work rather than have a long list of if...else with typeguards for each.

```js
// Test payloads (parsed from json, cast here to IPayload to simulate that)
const alphaPayload = { kind: 'alpha', alpha: 'a' } as IPayload;
const betaPayload = { kind: 'beta', beta: 1 } as IPayload;

// Goal: alphaPacket and betaPacket are of types AlphaPacket and BetaPacket respectively
const alphaPacket = PacketDecoder.decodePacket(alphaPayload);
const betaPacket = PacketDecoder2.decodePacket(betaPayload);

console.log(alphaPacket.getKind(), alphaPacket.getAlpha());
console.log(betaPacket.getKind(), betaPacket.getBeta());
```

I've tried the follow two methods so far:

```js
// Payload
interface IPayload {
  kind: string;
}

interface AlphaPayload extends IPayload {
  kind: 'alpha';
  alpha: string;
}

interface BetaPayload extends IPayload {
  kind: 'beta';
  beta: number;
}

// Packet
interface IPacket {
  getPayload(): IPayload;
  getKind(): IPayload['kind'];
}

class Packet<T extends IPayload> implements IPacket {
  constructor(protected payload: T) {}

  getPayload(): T {
    return this.payload;
  }

  getKind(): T['kind'] {
    return this.payload.kind;
  }
}

class AlphaPacket extends Packet<AlphaPayload> {
  getAlpha(): string {
    return this.payload.alpha;
  }
}

class BetaPacket extends Packet<BetaPayload> {
  getBeta(): number {
    return this.payload.beta;
  }
}

// Mapping
const kindToPacket = {
  alpha: AlphaPacket,
  beta: BetaPacket
} as const;

type KindMap = typeof kindToPacket;
type KindKey = keyof KindMap;
type KindToPacketConstructor<K extends KindKey = KindKey> = { [P in K]: KindMap[P] }[K]
type KindToPayload<K extends KindKey = KindKey> = { [P in K]: ConstructorParameters<KindMap[P]>[0] }[K]

// Type guards
function isValidKind(kind: string): kind is KindKey {
  return kind in kindToPacket;
}

function isValidPayload(payload: IPayload): payload is KindToPayload {
  return payload.kind in kindToPacket;
}

// Attempt 1
class PacketDecoder {
  static decodePacket<T extends IPayload>(payload: T): Packet<T> {
    if (isValidKind(payload.kind)) {
      const PacketClass = kindToPacket[payload.kind];
      return new PacketClass(payload); // ???
    }

    throw new Error(`Unknown ${payload.kind}`);
  }
}

// Attempt 2
class PacketDecoder2 {
  static decodePacket(payload: IPayload) {
    if (isValidPayload(payload)) {
      return PacketDecoder2.makePacket(payload.kind, payload);
    }

    throw new Error(`Unknown ${payload.kind}`);
  }

  static makePacket<K extends KindKey>(kind: K, payload: KindToPayload<K>) {
    const PacketClass: KindToPacketConstructor<K> = kindToPacket[kind];
    return new PacketClass(payload); // ???
  }
}
```

[View in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/PTAEAUEME8BsHtIBMBQBLAdgFwKYCcAzSAYx1AEko5ElQBvFUUAa0yQC5QBnLPTAcwDcKAL4p02fEVKgAgrAAOAC0hUEyUDgAeuDEi4U1NeoxZtOAckiKVF4U2vLInHnwxDR4zLkIkyAIRwsVRh1Wm1dfUNQ4wYmVj1LACMgyDtTFODODABXAFsUvGExFBAIEmYgiR9pMkoKoJMmfiCjZAAKAEpOeupke1AWrABpNi6etqQAbQsEpAsAXWLxYlhILgMoYkqsAB4AFU0dHD0DXrCAPlA0PIVYHDyTrDOtnabQYngMVxziLHg8O0FHh4Lg-jhaAoYshOPtOvQSs1WtCkONQIc4kxQHggjk8BhQFglGguAA6KF9JADRGDIKjPRo-YzOaLd5MHFYPEEokk8ko0lzameFCrdYGeROV6NCInKJSvYSlSTK6YoaKyBo1wCNnY3H4wnEskUsKkxwqIUlUUbUCBYLyo6RTYNPa2kKUlWmIautG5Ar4HUcrkG3nGmikzKQC3iMoAWUgCgUAhFXx4Zj0+3g9oAvO8zc45DYQtsggAaDKpTiu+WiUDrD4prDCFBYaAKMj0pBxhSgHMttvwAhppAZ+XCPvttjDHDQHssacD0Adrtj1sT9OZ50AYQbeF+-zwu2GDtlBg7U5nObP06uObooCm4GuBOGC04S-jD4WoBEUxfzdXi5sCOKKHsepyAXo56zle0A3vQ96Ppgi6vqA27fLwe4AlAeCQI8PhcIebBdp+FxTAADF+P5-qUYD7AB-A5JAeD6CgBA5BgfxoF81xcAAatYaBIB27RzC4vACN0Q48RBQnTu8gb6nMT5DsBxaNsKbEcVgXEEiS-GwIJkxAiiEwopJoYaCSMnAZS8l6gSFlIAKbDKXMqk7MsNFyFguC3FgoAAIwims1rygAIjgnxIP6mI8JA2nEKA0VRTg8oHGBUTnDQFzGZSsKSWl+weli1yDu0ekCUJYyOc5eidPCmIlZ86HlGpm4hQYOZuRualTDVcxLKYJUKQSGA4AA7q1OztWKuVhJ0gigGUAD8q1Dd+4glUSIKTWNk0AKJ4CCgIAAYAKoYMwGDwONBIACR0P1bAiCdC2mGIJRlLIPkPAo-kAEzBWKU1BBFKV4P97xxQlSWRfA0XynNNCmZSDXrWgZUVQZSBGY59U6uy9kg1gYPw-g-2knkkCVIjT16CWoB4wMTA0kw203aAe2gIdx3tOdl3XbdoAPXTSAvW9LObdwwQw1TNPOqBMrgTBOWiYuDOOW+QEbpSh4XGjTUNsTM0bFr67ymhPx-ACeuzt18pTANzO6py+pcxbHVI8gC1LWAq3Le9wplPsOCpo5BjGXgXAQqABAgnkoAAFZcF8DPEOs-lKPgZD-NEtm51wNw5GsuAGvFnTJi1eaTLOd5q1YhYWAzeaWGk361i8KLCM1qYRjXt5DskqRN6AEacAF7d1ll-TRmAADiiCwJw1fOrWeij6k9pMWQC7juKhZb+vVarziXBtpxABuOCwNAlepivamzuFcPRXgpLJWTiMr6j3dG33q85mfuDCmH8EbOnaP-H+KwUzwHuKSBA-B2gPx2KSIYwlOjNwPs6VBQR1RdDej3WBOB4HwEQf-NSOCRhjAwRvO02CvSpHwYIIAA)

The next step is to define a PacketHandler class which can hopefully take the result of decodePacket and pass it along to a handleKind(packet) function e.g. handleAlpha(packet: AlphaPacket) and handleBeta(packet: BetaPacket);

Answer (score 0):

> Test payloads (parsed from json, cast here to IPayload to simulate that)

If I understand correctly, you get arbitrary JSON data at runtime, that could be any `IPayload` (here `AlphaPayload` and `BetaPayload`)?

If so, then your:

> Goal: alphaPacket and betaPacket are of types AlphaPacket and BetaPacket respectively

...is unfortunately impossible to achieve, because TypeScript does *not* actually run your code. So if the type cannot be statically inferred more precisely than `IPayload`, then no matter how smart your decoder is, including using plenty if...else or switch typeguards, it cannot return any narrower packet than the union of all packets that can be produced by any `IPayload`.